# position absolute contenteditable long content issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, tinymce

Please check the [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/elelowwaydi_/0uh2rnzt/14/) and write a long text on the contenteditable element.

whenever the contenteditable content exceeds to its parent boundary, the parent div contents will push to the left.

```
<div class="voucher-template">
   <div class="voucher-background"></div>
   <div class="content-editable" contenteditable="true">
      sample text
   </div>
</div>

.voucher-template {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.voucher-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}
.content-editable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 350px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
 }
```

EDIT: it's actually a voucher editor. you can drag and move the contenteditable element. I just didn't include the plugins (jqueryUI draggable and TinyMCE) because it's purely html css issue not js plugins.
[editor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRfkU.jpg)

EDIT: I have updated the demo with a jquery ui draggable enabled to avoid confusion. the contenteditable is draggable and editable.

Comment: Ok...still we have no clue what you actually wanted to do...expand to the right...break to a new line and have it justified to the right...?

Comment: sorry, please try the demo. edit the contenteditable element with a very long text.
the issue is why is the parent content moves to the left. 
I have updated the question, and kindly please see the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to make the text flow further to the left when needed, why not just use right-aligned text?

```
.content-editable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px dashed gray;
  }
```

This will force the text to still be on the right hand side, but allow for cases where there would be overflow.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5kgq7Lh1/

Comment: sorry, but the contenteditable element is draggable, you can position it anywhere inside it's parent element. I updated the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Two Solutions

1. Get rid of `.voucher-background` because that's what you see being pushed to the left. What is the logic of having a sibling tag at 100% x 100% in a fixed confined space? In the demo, I have moved the teal background where it should've been: `.voucher-template`. BTW how big is this voucher number because at a certain length you can't drag the editable around because it's contained.
2. Or you can remove `left:350px` replace it with `right:0`. Next add a drag event handler and set `right` and `bottom` to `auto`.

> ```
> drag: function(event, ui) {
>   $(this).css({
>     "right": "auto",
>     "bottom": "auto"
>   });
> }
> ```

---

### Demo

```js
$('.content-editable').draggable({
  containment: 'parent'
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.voucher-template {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #808080;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* This was moved from that useless .voucher-background */
  background-color: teal;
}

.voucher-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-editable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: 350px;
  /* right: 0 */
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px dashed gray;
  &:hover {
    cursor: move;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="voucher-template">
  <div class="voucher-background"></div>
  <div class="content-editable" contenteditable="true">
    sample text
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: sorry, but the contenteditable element is draggable. positions top and left are dynamic. I can't define a position: right to the element. I have updated the question thanks.

Comment: Yeah, can't help without the plugins because  what you just claimed made no sense at all.